# ASMX Service Through HTTP Get vs REST

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

What is the difference between an asmx service that allows people to access it via http GET (or POST), without using SOAP requests vs a restful web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. A RESTful service could be implemented using any server side technology including ASMX. Also a RESTful doesn't imply the usage of a GET verb. In a RESTful service you are using all the HTTP verbs. It's just that there are no SOAP envelopes.

Comment: I was just under the impression that you could not implement a restful API using ASMX

Comment: @Henry Black, it's much more difficult, you will have far less control, and assuming ASMX is a deprecated technology I see absolutely no point in implementing anything with it, not only a RESTful API.